# how to set the center point and radius of a pie chart

Tags: highcharts, size, center

how to set the center point and radius of a pie chart so that the center point is in the top left corner, or so that the pie chart fills the entire plot area;
When setting the center of a pie chart to 0, if the chart is not positioned exactly in the top left corner but has a slight distance from it;
When I set the size to 100%, the chart still does not fill the page;
I tried setting spacing and margin, but it did not achieve the desired effect

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="zh">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <title>HighChart-3D饼图</title>
</head>

<!-- 1.通过CDN的方式引入HighChart -->
<script src="https://code.hcharts.cn/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-3d.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/cylinder.js"></script>
<!-- 暂时没用到 -->
<!-- <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script> -->


<body>
  <!-- 2.创建容器 -->
  <!-- margin: auto; position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; -->
  <div id="container" style="width: 900px;height:600px;background-color: #ccc;"></div>
  <script>
    // Set up the chart
    const option = {
      "plotOptions": {
        "pie": {
          "innerSize": "50%",
          "cursor": "pointer",
          "depth": 44.25,
          // "startAngle": 0,
          "size": "100%",
          "slicedOffset": 30,
          "center": [
            "0%",
            "0%"
          ],
          "allowPointSelect": false,
          "showInLegend": true,
          "point": {
            "events": {}
          }
        }
      },
      "exporting": {
        "enabled": false
      },
      "credits": {
        "enabled": false
      },
      "legend": {
        "layout": "vertical",
        "verticalAlign": "top",
        "symbolHeight": 12,
        "backgroundColor": "transparent",
        "itemStyle": {
          "fontFamily": "微软雅黑",
          "color": "rgba(0,0,0,1.00)",
          "fontSize": 12,
          "fontStyle": "normal",
          "fontWeight": "normal"
        },
        "align": "right",
        "squareSymbol": false,
        "symbolWidth": 24,
        "enabled": false,
        "symbolRadius": 3
      },
      "series": [
        {
          "dataLabels": {
            "distance": 30,
            "useHTML": true,
            "style": {
              "fontFamily": "微软雅黑",
              "color": "rgba(26,26,26,1.00)",
              "fontSize": "12px",
              "fontStyle": "normal",
              "fontWeight": "normal"
            },
            "enabled": false //change true -> false
          },
          "data": [
            {
              "sliced": false,
              "color": "rgba(101,145,249,1.00)",
              "name": "河北",
              "y": 15989599.2,
              "attributes": {
                "MAINDIMMEMBER_NAMECOLUMN": "河北",
                "MAINDIMMEMBER_KEYCOLUMN": "130000",
                "MAINDIM_NAMECOLUMN": "DWMC",
                "MAINDIM_KEYCOLUMN": "DWBM",
                "DRILL_DOWN": "false"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "tooltip": {
        "backgroundColor": "rgba(50,50,50,1.00)",
        "borderColor": "rgba(50,50,50,1.00)",
        "useHTML": true,
        "style": {
          "fontFamily": "微软雅黑",
          "color": "rgba(255,255,255,1.00)",
          "fontSize": "12px",
          "fontStyle": "normal",
          "fontWeight": "normal"
        }
      },
      "title": {
        "style": {
          "fontFamily": "微软雅黑",
          "color": "rgba(34,34,34,1.00)",
          "fontSize": "14px",
          "fontStyle": "normal",
          "fontWeight": "normal"
        },
        "text": ""
      },
      "chart": {
        "options3d": {
          "alpha": 45,
          "enabled": "true"
        },
        // "margin": [
        //   0,
        //   0,
        //   0,
        //   0
        // ],
        "backgroundColor": "transparent",
        // "spacing": [
        //   0,
        //   0,
        //   0,
        //   0
        // ],
        "type": "pie",
        "events": {}
      }
    }
    const chart = new Highcharts.Chart("container", option);

  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I am not sure if I fully understand your requirements, but here is the centered pie chart: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/mvgxfwbn/ . If this not fullfill your requirements, could you please sent an example image of the target placement of circle?